# Como personalizo la barra de navegacion de bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, responsive, color, navbar, font-size

Quiero personalizar el color de fondo, tipografia, color de la tipografia y tamaño y no puedo. Probé con la hoja de estilo y dentro del codigo de la barra y no se modifica, tampoco encuentro la forma de que el menú se convierta en menú hamburguesa cuando lo pruebo en diseño adaptable.

```
''' 
<html>
    <body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <img src="images/logo3.ico" alt="Logo" width="80" height="74" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" />
          <div class="container-md">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Quiénes somos</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Adoptá</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tránsito</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Voluntariado</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Doná</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
             </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </body>
</html>
'''
```

Comment: ¿Con cuál hoja de estilo intentaste? Añádela a tu pregunta en un fragmento de código.

Comment: Esta es la hoja de estilo, puedo cambiar el fondo y la tipografia pero no el color de la misma, probe con todas las clases que aparecen, usandolas en la hoja de estilo no modifica nada, solo me lo toma con style en el principal y no quiero eso

    '''
    .container-fluid{
        background-color: coral;
        font-size: xx-large;
        font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
        
    }
    
    .nav-link{
        color: chartreuse;
    }
    '''

Comment: @Ariana, edita tu pregunta para agregar más detalles. Los comentarios son efímeros, y, como verás, el código es ilegible aquí.

Comment: Por cierto, lee acerca de la [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) en CSS. Esa es la razón de tu problema. Y por lo del menú hamburguesa: es porque el botón no está en tu navbar... Para eso la propia [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#supported-content) te muestra ejemplos básicos.